# Automator: Error when running a Word Count service in TextEdit

Tags: applescript, automator, textedit

I followed a brief [step-by-step guide](https://www.macworld.com/article/672819/) for adding **word count** functionality to **TextEdit**.

Note that the guide instructs: "It will ask you to choose a type for your document; click **Service**". However, probably due to version differences, instead one must choose **Quick Action**.

[image]

As the guide advises, I used this code:

```
osascript tell application “TextEdit” set word_count to count words of document 1 set char_count to count characters of document 1 set show_words to (word_count as string) & ” words. (” & (char_count as string) & ” characters.)” set dialog_title to “TextEdit Word Count” display dialog show_words with icon 1 with title dialog_title buttons {“Ok”} default button “Ok” end tell AppleScriptHereDoc
```

[image]

After creating the Action / Service and running it, I get the following error:

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “-: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-: -c: line 0: `osascript tell application “TextEdit” set word_count to count words of document 1 set char_count to count characters of document 1 set show_words to (word_count as string) & ” words. (” & (char_count as string) & ” characters.)” set dialog_title to “TextEdit Word Count” display dialog show_words with icon 1 with title dialog_title buttons {“Ok”} default button “Ok” end tell AppleScriptHereDoc'”
```

[image]

The guide is from Feb 23, 2018 (over 5 years ago at the time of this writing), so that may have something to do with it. Hopefully there's a simple fix though.

Comment: By the way, you should accept your own answer. I don't think you get any rep for it but others will see that the question has an accepted answer when they come across it in searches.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...

It turns out there *was* a simple answer. I needed to go to [the original post by Tony T1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6892543?answerId=27886654022#27886654022) and copy the code from there instead.

The article on the MacWorld page had the code improperly formatted, and that's why it didn't work. It should be as follows:

```
osascript <<-AppleScriptHereDoc

tell application "TextEdit"

  set word_count to count words of document 1

  set char_count to count characters of document 1

  set show_words to (word_count as string) & " words. (" & (char_count as string) & " characters.)"

  set dialog_title to "TextEdit Word Count"

  display dialog show_words with icon 1 with title dialog_title buttons {"Ok"} default button "Ok"

end tell

AppleScriptHereDoc
```

Leaving this here in case others find it useful.

<sub>There is one remaining inconvenience, which is that it always calculates the word count from *all* the text in the TextEdit window, instead of only the selected portion of text. But it can be worked around by pasting into a new TextEdit window when wanting to get the word count. If anyone knows a way to make it target only the *selected* text, please drop a comment. I couldn't get Automator to allow me to specify that.</sub>

Comment: If you use UI scripting, you can copy the selection to the clipboard and then get the words of that. You don't need to put it in another document first.